# Get all text before SelectionStart and after SelectionEnd

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection-api

I am creating a text editor from scratch.

**code for getting bold**

```
$('#bold').click(function(){

            var start = window.getSelection().toString();

            var bolded = '<b>' + start + '</b>';
            var cursorPositionBegin = $('#TextEditor').prop("selectionStart");
            var cursorPositionEnd = $('#TextEditor').prop("selectionEnd");
// to check 
                alert(bolded);
            })
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<table width="50%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <span><input type=button value="B" id="bold"></span>
                </div>
                <div contenteditable="true">
                    <textarea cols="47" rows="23" placeholder="editor" id="TextEditor"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I click #bold for a selected set of characters I want to add **characters** in the #TextEditor. I thought maybe getting the beginning and ending position of cursor could help break up and join the begin and end together along with the **characters** to form what I require.

I also use jQuery

[update 1]
Or is there an alternate method to do what I require?
[update 2]
added  `contenteditable="true"` to div where #TextEditor id placed

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: What text do you want to add before start and after end?

Comment: Anything that is typed in the #TextEditor and I want to make something bold selection in the typed text .

Comment: `textarea` will not support any other elements inside it!

Comment: @weBBer meaning, like <b>something</b>, then it does

Comment: `<textarea>` element will not alow you to add `<b>` tag inside it, you will have to use `contenteditable="true"` div for your requiremnet.

Comment: @weBBer I have never come across what you are saying....If that textarea is inside a div you say but what if its in a table like my code?

Comment: What I meant is that if you are going to use `<textarea>` as an editor the bold style will not be applied to it, for that you will have to use `contenteditable` in the div and implement your editor to that div.

Comment: @weBBer I am using a table not div or lets assume I am using a table.  I have made the necessary changes in my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @weBBer said you will not allowed to add tag inside textarea element use div with attribute contenteditable="true" instead

```js
$('#bold').click(function(){
  var string = window.getSelection().toString();
  var bolded = '<b>' + string + '</b>';
  var selC, range;
      if (window.getSelection) {
          selC = window.getSelection();
          if (selC.rangeCount) {
              range = selC.getRangeAt(0);
              range.deleteContents();
              range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(bolded));
          }
      } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
          range = document.selection.createRange();
          range.text = bolded;
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="50%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <span><input type=button value="B" id="bold"></span>
                </div>
                <div contenteditable="true" style="height: 300px;width: 300px;border: 1px solid black">
                    
                </div>
            </div>  
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Great bro.. but don't generate it as text, generate as bold HTML.

Comment: @X10nD If you had you should have mentioned that in your Question, you are experienced in *StackOverflow* so you should know the method of posting a Question. It's ok you can convert this answer as you needing using this code.

Comment: @weBBer You are right but I thought to just slog myself to possibly get the code working and then come over to ask a question :)