# Write HTML tag in one div and see WYSIWYG in the other div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am typing HTML tags in TextEditor and want to preview it in TextEditorPreview without any HTML tags but for some reason the html tags appear in TextEditorPreview

```js
$('#TextEditor').keyup(function() {
  document.getElementById("TextEditorPreview").innerHTML = document.getElementById("TextEditor").innerHTML;

  document.getElementById("TextEditorPreview").html();
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="TextEditor" style="height: 300px;width: 300px;border: 1px solid black"></div>

<div id="TextEditorPreview" placeholder="preview" style="height: 300px;width: 300px; border: 1px solid #cccccc;"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("TextEditorPreview").html();` What is this for?

Comment: trial and error @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: In this case, [error](http://prntscr.com/khcd81).

Answer (score 1):

you should fill text of TextEditor to TextEditorPreview div

```
var text = $("#TextEditor").text();
$("#TextEditorPreview").html(text );
```

Example:

```js
$('#TextEditor').keyup(function() {
  var text = $("#TextEditor").text();
  $("#TextEditorPreview").html(text);
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="TextEditor" style="height: 300px;width: 300px;border: 1px solid black"></div>

<div id="TextEditorPreview" placeholder="preview" style="height: 300px;width: 300px; border: 1px solid #cccccc;"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: for some reason it does not work, its the same tag as in TextEditor to TextEditorPreview in the code.  Your code works good

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you type `<`, the contenteditable gets `&lt;` because it's trying to represent the actual character, not the beginning of a tag.

The simplest way is to use a `textarea` for the place you're typing instead. Also, remove the `document.getElementById("TextEditorPreview").html();` line, which wouldn't do anything if it works, and throws an error (because `html` isn't a method of native DOM elements):

```js
$('#TextEditor').keyup(function() {
  document.getElementById("TextEditorPreview").innerHTML = document.getElementById("TextEditor").value;
});
```

```html
<textarea id="TextEditor" style="height: 300px;width: 300px;border: 1px solid black"></textarea>

<div id="TextEditorPreview" placeholder="preview" style="height: 300px;width: 300px; border: 1px solid #cccccc;"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you use <div contenteditable="true" id="TextEditor" style="height: 300px;width: 300px;border: 1px solid black"></div> instead of the <textarea>?

Comment: @X10nD - You *could*, but you'd have to un-HTML-escape what you got. What's the point of using a contenteditable `div` instead of a `textarea`, when what you want is `textarea` behavior? You can still style it, etc., the same.

Comment: I don't want to use textarea because this is a text editor I am coding from scratch.  also "document.getElementById("TextEditorPreview").innerHTML = document.getElementById("TextEditor").value;" gives me undefined


this might give you a hint - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51797420/get-all-text-before-selectionstart-and-after-selectionend/51797533?noredirect=1#comment90552153_51797533

Comment: @X10nD - The change definitely works; see the live example above. But if you want a contenteditable `div`, see [Alireza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51798252/157247) (which is what I would have posted in response to your comment if he/she hadn't already done so).

Comment: I saw it.. 


This might give you a hint - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51797420/get-all-text-before-selectionstart-and-after-selectionend/51797533?noredirect=1#comment90552153_51797533

Comment: @X10nD - What do I need a hint about? You have two solutions to your problem...?